# Counting the occurrences of a value in a column and storing to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Lets say I have a dataframe of names and ages, where name (type object) is the index and age (type int) is the only column.

I want to count the occurrences of each name, whether or not the name is repeated more than once, and store them in a dictionary. For example, if there are 7 Anns then the key-value pair in the dictionary would like {'Ann' : 7}. This doesn't seem to work:

```
name_dict = df.groupby(df['name']).count()
```

Thank you.

Comment: The above code should work as expected, what error did you get when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. If you have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Ann','Bob','Ann','Bob','Ann',], 'Age':[23,34,45,56,12]})
```

then running this:

```
df.groupby('Name').count().to_dict(orient='dict')['Age']
```

produces

```
{'Ann': 3, 'Bob': 2}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. My code returns an error orient 'dict' not understood

Comment: hmm. what version of pandas are you using? `pip show pandas`

Comment: actually you do not need that bit anyway, I think this should work as well `df.groupby('Name').count().to_dict()['Age']`